# Best way for tab layouts with Android 4?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, galaxy

I want to start app-development for Android. I'm not new to java but the android sdk confuses me when searching for the "best" way to create a tab layout.

My first app should be simple.. I just need about 3 pages.

What is the best way to implement a tab layout? Maybe you can also tell me what ways I could take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to make a tabbed Activity.

1- TabActivity with a very simple tutorial here : 
   http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/

2- Fragments with another simple tutorial here :
   http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/

As of late, using Fragments has become the norm so you might want to check that out.

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I have read something about ActionBars.. are they preferable?

Comment: Well, it depends really on what you need to do. ActionBars are usually used if you want to add actions like save or delete file in the ActionBar as well as navigation. So for only 3 pages you don't really want to use ActionBar.

Answer (score 1):

First it depends on your target android version. If you are planning for latest versions, then [Fragments](http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/) are best option for tab layout.

Comment: FYI: Fragments are supported all the way back to Android 1.5 or Android 1.6 with the support library :-)

Comment: "With support library" is important thing. I was just talking about integrated API.

Comment: There's really no difference though. Same stuff. The support library doesn't even switch to the native fragment API's if it's running on Android 3.0+, so it doesn't really matter.